# JSF onclick event on combobox

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I don't know how to implement onclick event on a combobox, my boss want me to do is once the user click a value in the combobox it automatically search and display all the value of the selected/click item. First question is it possible to have an onclick event on a JSF page without using any javascript/jquery? Right now I'm using ADF for designing the interface. Second question how can I implements this onclick event on my combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

1. Use a valueChangeListener and execute your query when it fires.
2. Set autoSubmit="true" and when the bound value changes, execute your query.

Comment: thanks It's working now, by the way sorry for the late reply I got it working now but why valuechangelistener not onlick event I mean lot's of people know onclick is a appropriate event to do if clicking a button.

Comment: @HeidiLilybeth because onClick is JS and everybody knows you need to avoid JS in ADF when possible since JS isn't good for the performance rate of your webapp

Answer (score 0):

Only selecting a value in a dropdown won't submit your form. This is not about JSF but HTML .. so without *any* JS i think it's not possible.

I do not know anything about ADF in special but in plain JSF you just have to add an ajax-event to your dropdown (e.g. in primefaces)

```
<h:form id="id1">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="id2" value="#{myBean.value}" 
                             immediate="true" editable="true" >
                <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{myBean.doSomeAction}" />
                <f:converter converterId="myConverter" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.availableOptions}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```